# What is loaded first? Primary key or foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When we hit a query to get some data out of table/tables, in what order the columns are loaded? What I am understanding is that the primary key is loaded first and then it creates the whole table. But, when there are references to and from other tables, what is loaded first? And if primary key is loaded first, is there any case where foreign key might be loaded first?

Comment: This is way to complex to explain.. Besides innodb has a copy of the primary key within secondary indexes

Comment: Why do you need to know? I'm no DB engine expert, so I have no idea whether any of your description in any way reflects the reality of how SQL queries get executed, but what problem are you facing which you think could be related to this? Are you thinking about JOIN clause restrictions, perhaps? Maybe looking at the query plan would answer your question, but tbh it's not entirely clear what you think is happening or what difficulty it's causing you.

Comment: SQL is a *declarative* language, not an *imperative* language. That means, by definition, the database engine is free to access, load, process, etc the data in any way it prefers. That is usually done, to take advantage of possible optimizations and retrieve the data as fast as it can. There's little you can do, except giving some "hints" to the SQL optimizer. Besides that, you can't control the internal processing. Why would you, in the first place?

Comment: The interviewer asked me about keys and what key(Primary or foreign) will be loaded first, to which I answered that it should be primary key because it is going to derive the whole table. Then he asked if there is any case where foreign key is loaded first?

Comment: "loaded first"...in a SELECT query, not sure that actually makes sense TBH. Was this for a DBA job, or what?

Comment: Seems the interviewer doesn't have a clue. The other option is that it was a trick question.

Comment: The interview was for software developer post.

Comment: I agree with The Impaler, I think they were either talking rubbish without knowing any better, or trying to catch you out deliberately (to see if you knew they were talking rubbish). It's hard to see how any of this relates to reality of how SQL engines operate (to the best of my admittedly limited knowledge) - maybe someone with more expertise will know, but so far all the comments and answers are basically along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You seem to misunderstand how databases work.  All the columns for a given row are inserted at the same time.  This is pretty much by definition -- the entire row is inserted or nothing at all, based on the ACID properties of databases.

When you are creating a table, you would normally declare the primary and foreign key relationships in the `create table` statement.  This also all takes place at the same time.

There is no concept of inserting some keys at one time and some at a later time.  I mean, you can insert a row with `NULL` values for foreign keys and `update` the values later.  When you insert a row, the primary key needs to be defined; it cannot be `NULL`, and it normally would not be modified later.

Comment: I _think_ OP is actually asking about how a SELECT query runs they said "query to get some data out of tables", rather than how the tables are created or rows are inserted.